# Get-AzsHealthReport is not recognized

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-stack

I tried to get Azure Stack identity health report according to the below document. But getting error if the packages are installed on power shell. 
[Link](https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-Tools/blob/master/Identity/README.md#retrieve-azure-stack-identity-health-report)

```
Get-AzsHealthReport : The term 'Get-AzsHealthReport' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:17
+ $healthReport = Get-AzsHealthReport -AdminResourceManagerEndpoint $Ad ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzsHealthReport:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Did you install the module follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-powershell-install?view=azs-1908)? Use the correct commands depends on your Azure Stack version, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-powershell-install?view=azs-1908#install-azure-stack-powershell

Comment: @JoyWang Yes. Then I reinstalled them and getting the same error. AzS version 1908

Comment: Did you confirm the installation?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-powershell-install?view=azs-1908#confirm-the-installation-of-powershell-1 And if you run `Get-Command -Name Get-AzsHealthReport`, what's the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps provided in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-powershell-install?view=azs-1908#install-azure-stack-powershell) on powershell as Admin.

Start Powershell in Admin mode and run the below steps:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

# Install the AzureRM.BootStrapper module. Select Yes when prompted to install NuGet
Install-Module -Name AzureRM.BootStrapper

# Install and import the API Version Profile required by Azure Stack into the current PowerShell session.
Use-AzureRmProfile -Profile 2019-03-01-hybrid -Force
Install-Module -Name AzureStack -RequiredVersion 1.7.2
```

Now install Azure Stack Tools:

https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-Tools/tree/master/Identity#download-azure-stack-tools

```
cd C:
mkdir Azure-Stack
cd .\Azure-Stack\
# Download the tools archive.
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
invoke-webrequest `...
# Expand the downloaded files.
expand-archive master.zip `...
# Change to the tools directory.
cd AzureStack-Tools-master
cd .\Identity\
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
Import-Module ..\Connect\AzureStack.Connect.psm1
Import-Module ..\Identity\AzureStack.Identity.psm1
Get-AzsHealthReport
```

You should now be able to run the command.

Hope this helps!